# Add a completion for sorting an Array

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a list of urls and I will scrape the data of the urls, it take a bit of time so I get each data one by one. but not in the correct order, and then, I will append this data to an array, then set this array to another array which populate data in a `UICollectionView`.
But I have to sort the final array as well, in my current approach, it sorts array when the data is on the screen, and you can their changing position

```
discoveryFeeds.append(scraper)
discoveryCollectionView.feeds = discoveryFeeds.sorted(by: {$0.feed.createdAt > $1.feed.createdAt})
```

I want to change it something like that, knowing when the sorting is done that I can do the rest of the process after that

```
discoveryFeeds.append(scraper)
discoveryFeeds = discoveryFeeds.sorted(by: {$0.feed.createdAt > $1.feed.createdAt})

// and when sorting is done - send to collectionView
discoveryCollectionView.feeds = discoveryFeeds
```

could anyone help me on that. Thanks

Comment: I understand what you want to do but not what you are asking, what is the problem with implementing your second code sample?

Comment: In the second code, looks like it goes the last line before the sorting is done, so in the result, the feeds is not in the correct order

Comment: Wouldn't the sort only happen after all data is loaded? Why would you need a completion handler for the sort and not just for the loading?

Comment: No it's not happen after all data is loaded, it happen everytime that a new data comes

Comment: No it doesn't look like that at all, please post a more complete example where the issue can be understood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorting is not asynchronous. The "sorting is done" when we proceed to the next line.

So, in your second example,

```
discoveryFeeds = discoveryFeeds.sorted(by: {$0.feed.createdAt > $1.feed.createdAt})

// and when sorting is done - send to collectionView
discoveryCollectionView.feeds = discoveryFeeds
```

...indeed, we do not set `discoveryCollectionView.feeds` until the the sorting *is* done.